# sender's address displayed rather than his name while sending with SimpleMailMessage in java

Tags: java, spring, email

I send mail using SimpleMailMessage from org.springframework.mail package.But on the receiver side shows sender's address.I want to set his name.What method will use for this?Is there any method that available in SimpleMailMessage Class?I am using spring with hibernate.

code

```
 public void sendmail(){
 String emailSubject = "Test Message";                                          
 String emailBody = "For testing";
 SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();     
 simpleMailMessage.setTo("sendermailid@gmail.com");
 simpleMailMessage.setCc("receivermailid@gmail.com");
 simpleMailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
 simpleMailMessage.setText(emailBody);
 mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `My Name <myemail@gmail.com>`?

Comment: I tried that code.But no change in the result

Comment: The sender's address is set through `setFrom`, which I don't see in your code. Have you actually invoked `setFrom("My Name <myemail>")` ?

Comment: Thank you so munch...Its working

Answer (score 11):

Use Spring's [MimeMessageHelper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html) to set sender name *and* address.

```
        MimeMessagePreparator mailMessage = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(
                    mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");

            message.setFrom(senderEmail, senderName);
            [...]
        };
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
```

See also my code snippet [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123271/how-to-make-java-string-colored-when-sending-mail-using-simplemailmessage-class).

Answer (score 0):

I had problem where sender's name is not displayed.
The property I had in my spring application.properties file was as

**`sender.email.address=Some Name <noreply@somedomain.com>`**.

I checked many options, none of them worked, except a simple **hyphen (-) inclusion**. I have just added a hyphen in the email address as below and it started working

**`sender.email.address=Some Name <no-reply@somedomain.com>`**.

Let me know your suggestions if you have any better fix, I'm ready to learn.